# Obtaining Address Components with Google Place_id

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to request address components for a location using Google Maps "Place_id".  My code is as follows:

```
    varTestLink = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=" + googleAPIKey()
    $.get(varTestLink, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, "jsonp");
```

When running this the following error occurs:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement "error_message" : "This API
>   project is not authorized to use this API.

Please let me know if what I am trying to do is possible.  Any assistance is appreciated.  I am a self taught amateur web developer.

Thanks, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The places-API doesn't support JSONP, to request places-details on clientside use the [places-library of the  Maps-Javascript-API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests)

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the process to authorize your use of APIs (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/places/auth))? You also need to pass your key in each call. Example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json
  ?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362
  &radius=500
  &types=food
  &name=harbour
  &key=YOUR_KEY
```